# Page not displayed on my website

Tags: apache, web

I'm trying to put together my website but I'm experiencing a very weird behaviour. I have an html resource named y6.html in my www directory in the root directory of the website. It worked very fined until yesterday when suddenly when accessing it it sends me a void webpage with an empty head and an empty body (not a 404).
Also I realized after one point that I would change the css on the website but that the changes I made would be on the ftp server at the right place but the website would still display the old version I had not modified even after emptying the cache.

The page is : http://www.dronecontrast.com/y6.html

Any clue on what's causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an HTML error. Your `<title>` is not closed as usual. You must use `</title>` to close it.

Answer (score 0):

`</title>` is missing. Add the slash and try again

Comment: <title>Dronecontrast...<title> should be <title>Drone...</title>

Answer (score 0):

Just looking through the page source of that web page, you have made an error with the title tag. On your closing tag you have missed your "/". Put that in and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup is wrong. Please check nesting of title,head and body inside your html tag. Please consider using a text editor like Notepad++ / Sublime Text and check whether the tags are closed and nested properly.

In your markup Title tag should be closed.

Comment: Cool, then it should show you the tag nesting when you click on any tab. Next time if the console is not showing any error, then there is a problem in your markup.

Comment: thanks I didn't know the website would display a blank page in case of incorrect markup, I thought it would still display a broken page

Comment: For CSS, it should work after clearing the cache. If you are not sure if you cleared the cache properly, try in an other browser. Even then if it is not working, make sure the CSS files are linked to the webpage correctly. Even then, if it is not working, Post the code here and explain please.

Comment: @ulkar as you forgot put '/' in the the title tag, the browser thought, it have 2 title tags which is not allowed and all became blank. That is why HTML insists proper nesting.